# How to concatenate multiple rows values of a column into single column in sql without xml path

Tags: sql-server, xml

Hi i am trying concatenate values of multiple rows in a column to a single column . I can achieve it by using **FOR XML PATH('')** .But is there any alternative solution for concatenating in sql server.

```
StudentName
-------------
Mary
John
Sam
```

and the expected output should be like

```
StudentName
-------------
Mary, John, Sam
```

by using this i can achieve

```
select Name + ', ' AS 'data()'  from NAMES FOR XML PATH('')
```

but without using **XML PATH('')** is there any alternatives..?

Comment: Not really; if there were a simple way, no one would recommend `for xml path`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the info .But thing is am trying to query into another tool which supports sql queries , its not accepting XML PATH

Comment: How  many names do you have?

Comment: around 20 to 30

Comment: What is *into another tool*?

Comment: @Shnugo Enterprise architect

Comment: Is this issue solved? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate names using recursive CTEs:

```
with s as (
      select s.*, row_number() over (order by studentname) as seqnum
      from students
     ),
     cte as (
      select studentName as names, seqnum
      from s
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select cte.names + ',' + s.studentName
      from cte join
           s
           on s.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select top 1 cte.names
from cte
order by seqnum desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution I'd not advise normally (I'd prefer the XML PATH solution):

```
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @Result = @Result + ',' + Name
FROM NAMES;

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Result,2,10000)
```